# Embed iPhone xib in iPad UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm developing 2 iOS apps; a iPhone app and an iPad app. Both have different purposes and functions, but I'd like to (once it's complete) embed the iPhone views into the iPad app as a preview.

(in the iPad app) I have a tab view controller, it loads various controllers and the last one will be a Preview. I'd use half (landscape mode) of the screen for some final settings and the other half to preview what will be produced.

My questions are:
Is this doable?
Is it allowed by Apple?

I've seen other discussions where people want to embed other, App Store apps from other developers. I'm not trying to do this; I only intend to embed the app I have the code for.

I'm just not sure the direction to look in to get this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put both of them in the same project, and use a simple iPhone/iPad in `AppDelegate.m` to start the app with the appropriate View Controller.

That way you can present the iPhone app within iPad app by simply showing a view controller. Apple won't reject since technically it's still only 1 app.

To produce and submit 2 apps from the same project, create another Target. You can set bundle identifier / device type / etc per Target.